# Splitting an existing innodb table into separate files

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm wondering if  its possible to split an existing InnoDB table into multiple files. I understand that if you specify the `innodb_file_per_table` prior to creating the tables; they are split into separate files. But I have an existing database that is 150GB; and I now need to move a table to another machine.

Normally it wouldn't be a problem. But I noticed that when you use InnoDB and try to truncate/drop a table; the space isn't reallocated on the disk (ie, the `ibdata1` doesn't reduce in size [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341)). This is a problem as the reason I'm moving the table is due to space issues on my current server. Hence why I'm trying to split this existing `ibdata1` file into separate files for tables. This will then give me the flexibility to reallocate the space on disk once I have moved the table.

Comment: Can you copy the tables into another database (INSERT INTO db2.tablename SELECT * FROM db1.tablename) to get the desired files, then delete the old database and rename?

Comment: ah yes, this is a good idea. Space is still the issue I'm having though; I will give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: possibly renaming the table will also split it up, ALTER TABLE foo RENAME TO foo2

Comment: @nos thanks; I'm just worried about doing that as the tables are quite large. I tried @Dan Grossman's suggestion but it didn't create separate files for the new tables; and I'm using `innodb_file_per_table`. Odd.